# inputing numpy array images into pytorch neural net

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, tensor

I have a numpy array representation of an image and I want to turn it into a tensor so I can feed it through my pytorch neural network.

I understand that the neural networks take in transformed tensors which are not arranged in [100,100,3] but [3,100,100] and the pixels are rescaled and the images must be in batches.

So I did the following:

```
import cv2
my_img = cv2.imread('testset/img0.png')
my_img.shape #reuturns [100,100,3] a 3 channel image with 100x100 resolution
my_img = np.transpose(my_img,(2,0,1))
my_img.shape #returns [3,100,100] 
#convert the numpy array to tensor
my_img_tensor = torch.from_numpy(my_img)
#rescale to be [0,1] like the data it was trained on by default 
my_img_tensor *= (1/255)
#turn the tensor into a batch of size 1
my_img_tensor = my_img_tensor.unsqueeze(0)
#send image to gpu 
my_img_tensor.to(device)
#put forward through my neural network.
net(my_img_tensor)
```

However this returns the error:

```
RuntimeError: _thnn_conv2d_forward is not implemented for type torch.ByteTensor
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the input you give to your network is of type ByteTensor while only float operations are implemented for conv like operations. Try the following

```
my_img_tensor = my_img_tensor.type('torch.DoubleTensor')
# for converting to double tensor
```

Source [PyTorch Discussion Forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/runtimeerror-thnn-conv2d-forward-is-not-implemented-for-type-torch-bytetensor/17682/3)

Thanks to [AlbanD](https://discuss.pytorch.org/u/albanD)

Comment: It was actually FloatTensor, but thank you, your comment lead me to finding the answer.